# PHP ODATA XML parsing with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, odata

I have the following being returned as XML from source:

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:ID>30</d:ID>
    <d:Name></d:Name>
    <d:ProfileImageUrl>default.png</d:ProfileImageUrl>
    <d:ThumbnailUrl>default.png</d:ThumbnailUrl>
    <d:FavoriteCount m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:FavoriteCount>
    <d:ViewCount m:type="Edm.Int64">12030</d:ViewCount>
    <d:LastMonthViewCount m:type="Edm.Int64">1104</d:LastMonthViewCount>
    <d:LastWeekViewCount m:type="Edm.Int64">250</d:LastWeekViewCount>
    <d:LastDayViewCount m:type="Edm.Int64">21</d:LastDayViewCount>
    <d:CreationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2011-03-28T13:46:54.227</d:CreationDate>
    <d:Enabled m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Enabled>
    <d:UrlSafeName>t-boz</d:UrlSafeName>
    <d:LastDayFavoriteCount m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:LastDayFavoriteCount>
    <d:LastWeekFavoriteCount m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:LastWeekFavoriteCount>
    <d:LastMonthFavoriteCount m:type="Edm.Int64">0</d:LastMonthFavoriteCount>
    <d:IsOnTour m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsOnTour>
    <d:TodayRank m:type="Edm.Int32">6272</d:TodayRank>
    <d:WeekRank m:type="Edm.Int32">6851</d:WeekRank>
    <d:MonthRank m:type="Edm.Int32">6915</d:MonthRank>
    <d:AllTimeRank m:type="Edm.Int32">7973</d:AllTimeRank>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

I am retrieving this via file_get_contents then creating via SIMPLEXMLElement. However I am unable to access the content->properties fields (ie. ID, Name, ProfileImageUrl, etc). All I see from the SIMPLEXMLElement is the following:

```
[content] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => application/xml ) )
```

Any thoughts on how I get this data?

Thanks!

Comment: Your XML is invalid, the `m` and `d` namespace prefixes need to be defined in the document.

Comment: This is very dodgy XML. It uses namespace prefixes on its elements but it doesn't bind those namespace prefixes.

Comment: The feed has this at the top.. Sorry I excluded it earlier.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://odata.vevo.com/v1/Catalog/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

Answer (score 5):

Accessing namespaced elements is easy with SimpleXML, you just tell the [`children()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) method which namespace to look in.

A *super basic* example would look like:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<content type="application/xml" xmlns:m="urn:m" xmlns:d="urn:d">
  <m:properties>
    <d:ID>30</d:ID>
    <d:ProfileImageUrl>default.png</d:ProfileImageUrl>
  </m:properties>
</content>
XML;

$content      = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// Quick way
// $properties = $content->children('m', TRUE)->properties->children('d', TRUE);
// echo $properties->ProfileImageUrl;

// Step by step
$m_elements   = $content->children('m', TRUE);
$m_properties = $m_elements->properties;
$d_elements   = $m_properties->children('d', TRUE);
echo $d_elements->ProfileImageUrl;
```